# How do I balance details vs business need in a gherkin test?

Tags: testing, cucumber, gherkin

I have a table that's going to have 3 timestamp columns: `created_on`, `updated_on`, and `applied_on`.

The first two are what you think.  The last one is the timestamp some related external action occurs.

My business users are writing tests. I don't want their tests to shatter if I change some detail in the code.  That is, the business tests should be testing business need, not technical implementation.

Here some gherkin:

```
Given we do all the setup for this example
When a row is created
Then created_on will be valid
And updated_on will be valid
And applied_on will be undefined
And created_on will equal updated_on
```

Now, this is completely logical and valid. And likely an anti-pattern. It is very low-level; we're talking about specific column names.

Take 2:

```
Given we do all the setup for this example
When a row is created
Then the created and updated dates are the same
And applied_on will be undefined
```

Maybe businessy? I don't know.

Finally, take 3:

```
Given we do all the setup for this example
When a row is created
Then the dates are appropriate for creation

Given we do all the setup for this example
When a row is updated
Then the dates are appropriate for update

Given we do all the setup for this example
When a row is acted upon
Then the applied date is set
```

So we see here gherkin tests of different levels of detail.  Where's the line between unit-test and business test? What if the non-coding QA people who are creating feature files want to be sure the dates are set 'just so'?

```
 Then the dates are appropriate for creation
```

is resilient enough, but how would this satisfy someone who wanted to be sure the dates were reasonable?  Sure, the underlying code seems to work. The coders can assure the testers that the steps code meets the needs of the requirements. But how would this appease any QA person worth their salt?

Comment: Unit tests cover stuff like that. Cucumber is for behavior driven development. The behavior for a user has nothing to do with audit columns in a database. Actually, I wouldn't even create unit tests for that. The database should handle that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenarios are all focused on how your table stores data. They need to be focused on why the data is important. Using cucumber to test that data is written to a table is just not productive. You can easily do that with a unit test, which will be

1. Easier to write
2. Much cheaper to run

Good cucumber scenarios work at much higher levels of abstraction, so that each scenario covers a large amount of ground. This is the only way you can justify the expense of running (and to a lesser extent) writing them.